# Android App - XML or java

Tags: android

I am currently starting to create an app for a small charity company. But I'm not entirely sure how to properly learn how to code for the Android OS. I have searched online for tutorials, but most stop at the same stage and only show you how to launch the "helloWorld" app.

My question is this:

1) Will using solely XML be sufficient to code an app? Does it require working in partnership with Java?

2) Does anyone know of any books, recommended books of course, that break everything down for you step-by-step?

Answer (score 2):

Android Developer site very good to give you all ideas. Start from [Hello, World](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/hello-world.html)

Answer (score 2):

1.) Not at all. XML is ONLY used for the layouts.

2.) There are a few books out there that I'm sure someone will come along and recommend, but I've found the tutorials [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/index.html) to be the best start.

Answer (score 0):

1) No, you can use XML for interface, but you can't write an Android app in XML :) You are not required to work with Java, but Android language is based on Java, so knowing Java is an advantage while learning to code.

2) Did you installed Eclipse and the plugin for Android?

The  [Android Training](http://developer.android.com/training/index.html) is pretty useful, and I've learnt a lot from the [tutorials](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html) and the [sample code](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/get.html) provided there. (The [Notepad](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/notepad/notepad-ex1.html) app is way more complex than the *Hello World* tutorial ;)!).

Also, take a look at the answers on that question: [How can I learn Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949818/how-can-i-learn-android)

Answer (score 0):

In your case, I'd look at [AppInventor](http://appinventor.googlelabs.com/about/) which allows you to create small Apps without coding (at least that's what it says, haven't used it yet myself)